# AlarmManager does not work

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, reboot

I have an alarm manager. It must work once per day. And alarm must exist if I remove app from task or if I reboot device. But when I reboot device, alarm is not exists. If i remove app from task, alarm is not exist too.

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
             if (isAlarmEnableded) {
            if (!isAlarmSheduled) {
                setAlarm();
                isAlarmSheduled = true;
              putInSharedPreferences(Boolean.toString(isAlarmSheduled));
            }
        } else {
            cancelAlarm(MainActivity.this);
            isAlarmSheduled = false;
            putInSharedPreferences(isAlarmSheduled);
        }

        super.onResume();
    }
```

`isAlarmEnableded` - SwitchPreference = true . If `isAlarmEnableded` -  I turn off the alarm.
`isAlarmSheduled` - value that I save in preferences. It displays the status of alarm

```
 private void setAlarm() {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(Constants.ALARM_INTENT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                Constants.PENDINGINTENT_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarmTime(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarmTime(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }

private long setAlarmTime() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

If current time > that sheduled time, I set alarm for tomorrow.

`Constants.ALARM_INTENT` - "com.blabla.AlarmReceiver".

**AlarmReceiver**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.setClass(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

NotificationActivity shows a dialog at the alarm time. 
Also I have a DeviceBootReceiver, that invokes `setAlarm()` method and put `isAlarmScheduled` in preferences.
**MAnifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.mypackage..AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.blabla.AlarmReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mypackage.DeviceBootReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I'm checking alarms by `adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt` . I need a stable alarm that works once per day in all cases. If I shut down app and restart it, alarm should be the same 
Alarm works in all cases, but not when I reboot device and when I remove app from task. Maby my code contains some mistakes. Help me to solve my problem because I dont know what I am doing wrong/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the boot receiver to initialize your alarm after booting the device , something like:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         List<Note> notes = dbHelper.getAllNotesAlarms();
    for (Note note : notes) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(note.getAlarm());
        Intent intent = new Intent(App.getAppContext(), AlarmService.class);
        intent.putExtra("NOTE_ID", note.getId());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(App.getAppContext(),
                (int) note.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am =
                (AlarmManager) App.getAppContext().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    } 
    }

}
```

Comment: I know. My receiver looks like you describe.It invokes setAlarm() method and put isAlarmScheduled in preferences . But it is not work

Comment: what about the com.mypackage.DeviceBootReceiver class , can you send the class file

Comment: protected void onResume() { setAlarm();   isAlarmSheduled = true;
              putInSharedPreferences(Boolean.toString(isAlarmSheduled));}

Answer (score 0):

you should add boot complete receiver than set your alarm again 
guide http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html